# Defining resource base for scalatra with embedded Jetty

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, scalatra

I have a scalatra based app with embedded jetty.

My final output structure is `/lib /bin /etc` and `webapp` is located under etc.

When launching the webapp there is the line which sets the `resourceBase` - what is this supposed to be set to in this case?

```
val context = new WebAppContext()
context setContextPath "/"
context.setResourceBase(???)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `WebAppContext` as your chosen ContextHandler in Jetty, you are constrained under all of the requirements for a WebApp.

Namely:

- `${resourceBase}/WEB-INF/classes/` is the primary source of classes
- `${resourceBase}/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar` is the secondary source of classes and webapp configuration
- `${resourceBase}/WEB-INF/web.xml` is the webapp descriptor (optional in Servlet spec 3.0+)
- `${resourceBase}/` is the lookup point for various methods in [`javax.servlet.ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) such as:

  - `String getRealPath(String path)`
  - `URL getResource(String path)`
  - `InputStream getResourceAsStream(String path)`
  - `Set<String> getResources(String path)`
- Requested resources that don't match any of your servlets or filters, will then be handled by the `DefaultServlet`, which might serve static resources (such as `*.html`, `*.css`, `*.js`) from the specified `${resourceBase}`

This just to name a few of the reasons to properly define your resourceBase.

Good Luck,